# How to Fix java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter with Spark Dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframes that I am trying to join. I'm trying to join the two dataframes by the second column ("C1")

```
Dataframe 1: a
Dataframe 2: b
```

I load the df like this: I load the CSV data (it is stored in snappy files) via df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quoteMode","NONE").option("delimiter", "|").load(/path/path/path)

I ran this code:

```
joined = a.join(b, a.C1==b.C1)
```

This runs immediately; then, when I try to run .head() on this joined dataframe, I get the following error:

```
ERROR CsvRelation$: Exception while parsing line: 
jkjsdklfsd9234lj23234hgy3234|394583495345|5|803|90245|A|NULL|HR44-200|3273205975|N|
Pacific|Y|asdf|asdf|437320597|023861998815|-1|NULL|2018-10-24 20:26:38|2018-10-24 
07:53:17|2018-10-19 02:30:19|2018-10-24 20:26:38|Stuff|2019-04-01 
12:10:02|2017-10-19 01:39:54|2037-01-01 00:00:00|2017-10-24 
13:54:05|N|Y|N|HR54-500|"1":"HR54","2":"C51-500".

java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
```

After looking online, it seems that the quotes are the issue (at the end of the error), but I don't know how to deal with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: The issue is not related to join. Please post how you load the CSV data.

Comment: @olik1 I load the CSV data (it is stored in snappy files) via df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quoteMode","NONE").option("delimiter", "|").load(/path/path/path)